# Why do Sets of Characters appear to be ordered?

Tags: clojure, set

I was always under the impression that Sets aren't ordered, but noticed that Sets of Characters *do* seem to be ordered:

```
(seq #{\e \c \b \z \a}) 

=> (\a \b \c \e \z)
```

If I introduce other kinds of characters, it seems as though they're being ordered according to the codes of the characters:

```
(seq #{\e \A \c \space \b \z \a})

=> (\space \A \a \b \c \e \z)
```

Why are characters being sorted according to their code, but Sets of numbers appear to have arbitrary ordering?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `Character/hashCode` is directly tied to the character's ordinal number, and sets are based on hashmaps. But if you introduce enough characters to start getting hash collisions, the apparent ordering doesn't entirely hold together:

```
; the whole alphabet is small enough to avoid collisions
user=> (apply str (set "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
; and observe the hashes are indeed sequential
user=> (map hash (set "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
(97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122)

; but go from 26 to 36 elements, and you start to see collisions
user=> (apply str (set "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
"abcdefghijklmno0p1q2r3s4t5u6v7w8x9yz"
user=> (map hash (set "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
(97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 48 112 49 113 50 114 51 115 52 116 53 117 54 118 55 119 56 120 57 121 122)
```

But of course as you know, this is not a defined behavior, but just how the implementation happens to work at the moment.

Now, you ask why this doesn't happen for numbers: the reason is, Clojure explicitly avoids it! `(.hashCode 1)` returns 1, because that's how Java defines its hashcodes. But [Clojure's `hash` function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/2a08ef40018f1b504602545603eec840b05b33b1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L1074) uses murmur3, which returns quite different values for numbers than just returning the input: `(hash 1)` yields 1392991556. I'm not an expert on this, but I believe the primary motivation for using murmur instead of Java's built-in hash function is avoiding hash collisions for security reasons. Timing attacks or something?

Comment: Interesting! So Characters use Java's hash implementation, while numbers use Clojure's?

Comment: Yes, there is simply no override in [`hasheq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/6dcb5e2/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Util.java#L164) for characters.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for the in depth analysis.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.